# SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Web Service Task Source info From File

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, ssis

I am working on an SSIS package where one of the purposes is to call an internal web service to send an email with attachments.

I am able to get the web service to work correctly when I hard code the data, such as To and From email address, in variables for the Web Service Task.

However what I really want to do is read the data for the web service from a file and then use that data to invoke the web service, however when I add a Data Flow Task to the package with a flat file source, the Flow correctly reads the data from the file, however it does not pass this data on to the Web Service Task. I would like to have an example of how to do this, if it requires some scripting I am ok with that I have much experience with C# programming.

Please note the screenshots showing what I am trying to do with SSIS:

[image: SSIS Package Control Flow]

[image: SSIS Package Data Flow]

Comment: How much data are we talking about? If it's just a couple of values (e.g. a one-row file) you might find that storing them in an SSIS variable in the data flow task and then reading them from there in the web service might be the way to go.

Comment: I am planning to invoke the Web Service no more than a dozen times each run, its not very many ops, only a few. Also I found a solution using C# code with a Script Task, but I am thinking that there is a way to implement this without have to code.